# Можно ли как-то вывести содержимое файла который находиться в облаке без его скачивания и регистрации в облако

Tags: python, flutter, dart

Мне надо открыть файл который находиться в облаке Mega. Сколько я уже не пытался все в пустую даже GPT дает ответ но не верный, подскажите люди добрые

Пробовал через модуль requests python, но он выдает тока содержимое html, а мне надо именно файла
Для решения данной задачи попрошу использовать ЯП, такие как

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А вы хотите доступ к своему файлу получить? Или чужому? Если к своему или чужому, нужна ссылка на файл из облака. Если файл не расшарен (т.е. доступ закрыт), то только при помощи паяльника во владельце, как в 90х можно получить файл ;)

Comment: ну к своему, я же не на столько глуп, что не понимать что не к своему не возможно. сама ссылка доступна и не зашифрована, через модуль не получается тк дает только хтмл содержание а мне надо именно содержание файла. Буду при много благодарен если оставишь тут ответ написанный на Python ибо Dart

Comment: Вы хоть ссылку на файл приведите.

Comment: А да, простите. Вот ссылка на файл - https://mega.nz/file/lfFiHKhB#mlsdwxLvAuwazXafXo4p2dYJwnPLRbnykvfBNs_Oy08

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/mega.py/

Comment: а без регистрации никак нельзя? Просто программой будут пользоваться другие люди еще в добавок